# Preconditions for Enumerables

Tags: .net, collections, code-contracts

Given

```
void ProcessSchedules(IEnumerable<Schedule> schedules)
{
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(Contract.ForAll(schedules,x => x.Date <= DateTime.Today))
    foreach( var schedule in schedules )
    {
       // Do something with schedule
    }
}
```

In this scenario, schedules will be enumerated twice. (Resharper gives me the warning) An alternative I do to most scenarios is to force the collection into a list at the beginning of the method, but given the nature of code contracts, no other code should precede the precondition. What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the options that I can think of in descending order of my personal preference.

- Use static checking rather than run-time checking. This way it will not have to enumerate the list at all to do the check. This option has the limitation that it is extrememly expensive. I don't have access to the static checker myself, as much as I would love to. So alternatively, you could...
- Change the definition of the method to work OK in the presense of future dates so that the check is unnecessary.

Like this:

```
void ProcessSchedules(IEnumerable<Schedule> schedules) 
{ 
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(schedules != null);
    foreach(var schedule in schedules ) 
    {
        if (schedule.Date <= DateTime.Today)
        { 
           // Do something with schedule 
        }
    } 
}
```

If that doesn't make sense for your program, then you could...

- Change the definition of the method to accept a list in the first place.

Like this:

```
void ProcessSchedules(List<Schedule> schedules) 
{ 
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(Contract.ForAll(schedules,x => x.Date <= DateTime.Today)) 
    foreach(var schedule in schedules ) 
    { 
       // Do something with schedule 
    } 
}
```

You have already said that forcing it into a list would be an option, so clearly this is a finite sequence of acceptable size. There is a high probability that the caller is using a `List<Schedule>` in the first place, or that there are other places where this implementation would be useful.

If you really want to keep the `IEnumerable` in your signature you could...

- Just ignore the warning.

With your original code:

```
void ProcessSchedules(IEnumerable<Schedule> schedules) 
{ 
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(Contract.ForAll(schedules,x => x.Date <= DateTime.Today)) 
    foreach( var schedule in schedules ) 
    { 
       // Do something with schedule 
    } 
}
```

I seriously don't see a problem in enumerating the list twice, and I am not even sure why Resharper would issue a warning for this.

If generating the schedules enumeration is an expensive operation, it doesn't matter, because you shouldn't normally include the contract validation in your release code anyway.

If the schedules enumeration is reading from a database, or something like that, then the contract isn't valid anyway, because the data could change between the validation and the processing. In that case it would be more correct for the method to accept a list or some other cached copy of the data that will not mutate.

Comment: I just read about `ReadOnlyCollection`. Can that be considered as an alternative in this case?

Comment: @John - Yes, I think `ReadOnlyCollection` would be a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two possibilities:

1. Ignore the ReSharper warning if you are sure that the double enumeration of the enumerable isn't going to bite you, maybe because it is an internal method and you know and will ever know all callers.
2. Create an overload of `ProcessSchedules` that accepts a `List<Schedule>`:

   ```
   void ProcessSchedules(IEnumerable<Schedule> schedules)
   {
       Contract.Requires(schedules != null);
       ProcessSchedules(schedules.ToList());
   }

   void ProcessSchedules(List<Schedule> schedules)
   {
       Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(Contract.ForAll(schedules,
                                                            x => x.Date <= 
                                                            DateTime.Today));
       foreach( var schedule in schedules )
       {
           // Do something with schedule
       }
   }
   ```

I am favoring version two, especially if it is a public method. The reason being that I have been burned by ignoring the warning just yesterday.

Comment: FWIW schedules come from NHib, so yeah I'll prolly get burned for 1. Haha

Comment: @John - If your data is coming from a database, then the contract is invalid. Data in a database can change at any moment without warning. Therefore, the contract can never be satisified. Contract checks are only appropriate on an object that will not mutate, either because it is immutable or the mutable object is only referenced by the calling thread.

Answer (score 1):

Someone will kill me, I know :-)

```
void ProcessSchedules(IEnumerable<Schedule> schedules)
{
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(Contract.ForAll((schedules = schedules.ToList()),x => x.Date <= DateTime.Today))

    // now schedules is a List<Schedule> :-) Note that the reference is still a 
    // IEnumerable<Schedule>, but you can cast it, like:

    List<Schedule> schedules2 = (List<Schedule>)schedules;

    foreach( var schedule in schedules )
    {
       // Do something with schedule
    }
}
```

This works [because](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691315%28v=VS.71%29.aspx):

> The result of a simple assignment expression is the value assigned to
>   the left operand. The result has the same type as the left operand and
>   is always classified as a value.

I'll add that i would make an extension method that checks if the passed parameter is already a `List<T>` or an `Array<T>` so that it doesn't create a second copy of it. Something like:

```
public static IList<T> Materialize<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enu)
{
    if (enu is IList<T>)
    {
        return (IList<T>)enu;
    }
    else
    {
        return enu.ToList();
    }
}
```

Clearly you could extend to check if `enu` is already a `IList<T>` instead of a "pure" `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: This is very much against the spirit of code contracts which wants side effect free expressions. This also leads to a strange contract, since it has a contract for `schedules = schedules.ToList()` and not for `schedules`. Since this expression becomes part of the documentation that's even user visible.

Comment: @CodeInChaos You already create a side-effect when you enumerate it. At least my side-effect won't create a worse sideeffect (reenumerating twice the IEnumerable>. For the documentation part, you are right, but you could write an extension method (like what I've wrote) called Materialize so that it's clearer what you are doing.

Comment: I like how Materialize works. Would that remove the R# warning in any case?

Comment: @Jonn I have to tell the truth... I don't have here the R# 6.0 and I don't have the Contract rewriter so I can't test :-( (I only have R# 5.1)

Comment: I didn't know it was called that. Anyway, tested it and unfortunately it doesn't remove the R# warning.

Comment: @Jonn Try the variant I've written now of `Materialize`... But I don't think it will change anything.

Comment: @Jonn Just tried it and the variant that returns an IList<T> works. I'll say they have made some code to recognize the pattern `myEnumerable = myEnumerable.ToList()/ToArray()`. After that you can make as many foreach on myEnumerable as you want without warning.

Comment: Works great. Still feels hacky but it works. I'd just have to choose between purity and practicality.

Comment: @xanatos - The original code in this answer does create a side-effect and it is much worse than the enumeration (which isn't really a side-effect since it doesn't change the state of the variable). When you change the compiler settings so that the contract validations are removed, then the cast to `List<Schedule>` will fail. Removing contract validations should not introduce bugs.

Comment: @John - The choice between "purity and practicality" is a false choice. Good design is good because it retains long-term value. Chasing bugs in hacky code that was written months ago is not an effective use of programmer time. Often the "practical" solutions are not practical at all. Good programming practices do not exist because they are mathematically beautiful. They exist because they save time and money. There are very good reasons why you should not be setting variables inside contract definitions. The irony of the thing is that the whole purpose of contracts is to avoid hacky code!